# Single-Sign-On (JSESSIONIDSSO Cookie) in Wildfly 9 not working behind Apache

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, cookies, single-sign-on, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 9.0.1.Final with single-sign-on to secure my backend and frontend with the following configuration:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <single-sign-on path="/"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        ...
```

In my development environment, everything is working fine. But if I use FORM login in production environment, where the wildfly is behind an apache server, clients only get `JSESSIONID` but *no* `JSESSIONIDSSO`.

The corresponding apache config is:

```
ProxyPass /user http://localhost:10080/user
ProxyPassReverse /user http://localhost:10080/user

ProxyPass /backend http://localhost:10080/backend
ProxyPassReverse /backend http://localhost:10080/backend
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because of couple of reasons:

- The domain name on the cookie will be reflecting the wildfly domain,
  which will be different than the actual domain, which is being used
  by the client.

and OR

- The path which is set on the cookie is different from the path from where the  reverse proxy call being made.

In any of the above case the `Set-Cookie` header will be received by the browser, its just that it will silently discard it.

You can add the following extra configuration in Apache to solve the issue

```
 ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /example.com /
 ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost example.com
```

Please refer to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain) for more details and check the error logs for Warning regarding cookies

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried that but it did not work. I also checked the server responses for my login calls. In production environment the `Set-Cookie` is not being sent by the server. So it does not seem to be a matter of the browser discarding the SSO cookie.